# MFC - On terminiation handler

Tags: mfc, event-handling

Is it possible to call a function to perform cleanup before my application closes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly. That is what the [CWinApp::ExitInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4zc2h84.aspx) virtual function is for.